# Does Yukari ever change back from being an alpaca in Paca Plus?

Tags: paca-plus

The premise of Paca Plus is rather amusing: the protagonist's girlfriend Yukari gets transformed into an alpaca. Having played the trial, it was pretty well-done, but the trial ends right when Yukari turns into an alpaca so it's difficult to judge the game based on that. I'm now at the point where I have to decide whether or not to buy the full game, with not quite enough information to make the decision.

If Yukari never changes back, and the whole game is just romance with alpaca Yukari, that wouldn't really be my cup of tea. To use a quote from the game:

[image]

However, if Yukari occasionally changes back to her human form, I could live with her being an alpaca most of the time. That seems like something that could be played up for great comedic value, and it wouldn't totally kill the romance.

So my question is, **does Yukari stay an alpaca forever, or does she switch back to being a human?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, Yukari does change back from an alpaca to a girl.

> The "curse of the alpaca" which was placed on Yukari is reversed by Kazuma accepting her and kissing her as an alpaca. 
>  [image] 
>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but there's a sequel that introduces a new character... a capybara. And Yukari returns to her "paca version".
No, i'm serious here.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you expanded this a bit more. :) - as it stands it sounds like much of an ideal answer to me,